# Find minterms using a boolean expression using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, digital-logic

I am using sympy library. I can compute SOP using min-terms

```
>>> from sympy.logic import POSform
>>> from sympy import symbols
>>> w, x, y, z = symbols('w x y z')
>>> minterms = [[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> dontcares = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1]]
>>> POSform([w, x, y, z], minterms, dontcares)
And(Or(Not(w), y), z)
```

I need help in calculating min terms from a Boolean expression.

Answer (score 1):

Check the link [Simplification and equivalence-testing](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html) and under `Simplification and equivalence-testing` you can find function `simplify()`. I hope it will help you with your problem.